# Using material ui data table in React, not able to access row data

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I am using the [material ui data table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-datatables) package in my React project.

Everything otherwise works as expected, but when I try to access the selected row(s) via its provided callback (Yep, I am using TypeScript):

```
import { MUIDataTableOptions } from "mui-datatables";
...
const options: MUIDataTableOptions = {
  onRowsDelete: (rows => {
      rows.data.map(r => console.log(JSON.stringify(r)));
 
  }),
  ...
}
```

At runtime, when select rows and clicking the delete icon, this callback only gives two indexes of the selected table row. But I need to access the data showing on the row in order to delete via request to backend.

How can I get the data of the selected row using this library/package when deleting rows?

Comment: check console if there is any error like `rows.data` is not a function and what is coming in `'r'`?

Comment: are you getting correct index ?

Comment: Only two indexes I found from console logs. I also thought the `rows.data` would return me data, but see only indexes, that's why post the question.

Comment: You could use `getRows` method. And by the way. It's sound so lame `(Yep, I am using TypeScript)`. Sound cool look like this `(Yep, I am using Zod)`.

Comment: @DSDmark Could you please be more specific, I searched the API doc, I don't find `getRows` method. How to call that in the `onRowsDelete` callback in my case?

Comment: Its `MUIDataTable` component to get the data of the selected rows